# Problems with One to many relationship Java JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem with my JPA.
Basically my Couriers are created by the program and the customer and parcels are created by user while running. When I try to add a new parcel  I add the object to parcel list in Customer and parcel list in Courier. But it crashes when tries to add to Courier parcel list. I create a courier object before calling my menu in the main class

And it throws the following error: 
During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: Courier: 
Id: 0
Name: null
Vehicle: null.

This is my code:

```
    @Entity
    @SequenceGenerator(name="cou_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)

    @SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
    public class Courier implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="cou_seq")
private int couId;
private String name;
private String vehicle;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "courier", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Parcel> plist = new ArrayList<>();

public Courier(){
}

public Courier(String nameIn, String vehicleIn){
    name = nameIn;
    vehicle = vehicleIn;
}

public void addParcel(Parcel p1){
    plist.add(p1);
    p1.setCo(this);
}

public int getCouId() {
    return couId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}

public void setCouId(int couId) {
    this.couId = couId;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setVehicle(String vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}

public List<Parcel> getParcel(){
    return plist;
}

public void setParcel(List<Parcel> parcels) {
    plist = parcels;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Courier: \nId: " +  couId + "\nName: " + name + "\nVehicle: " + vehicle;
}
```

//CUSTOMER CLASS

```
    @Entity
    @SequenceGenerator(name="cus_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)

    @SuppressWarnings("SeralizableClass")
   public class Customer implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="cus_seq")
private int cusId;
private String login;
private String password;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String dob;
private String address;
private String phoneNo;
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Parcel> plist = new ArrayList<>();


public Customer(){
}

public Customer(String loginIn, String passwordIn, String fnameIn, String lnameIn, String dobIn, String addressIn, String phoneNoIn, String emailIn){
    login = loginIn;
    password = passwordIn;
    fname = fnameIn;
    lname = lnameIn;
    dob = dobIn;
    address = addressIn;
    phoneNo = phoneNoIn;
    email = emailIn;
}

public void addParcel(Parcel p) {
    plist.add(p);
    p.setC(this);
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public List<Parcel> getParcel(){
    return plist;
}

public void setParcel(List<Parcel> parcels) {
    plist = parcels;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Customer: " + "\nID: " + cusId + "\nLogin: " + login + "\nFirst Name: " + fname + "\nSecond Name: " + lname + "\nDOB: " + dob + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nPhone No: " + phoneNo;
}
```

}

//PARCEL CLASS

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "par_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize =     1)

    @SuppressWarnings("SerializableClass")
    public class Parcel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "par_seq")
private int parId;
private double height;
private double width;
private double length;
private double weight;
private String receiver;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "cuId")
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "coId")
private Courier courier;

private static double price;

public Parcel() {
}

public Parcel(double heightIn, double widthIn, double lengthIn, double weightIn, String receiverIn) {
    height = heightIn;
    width = widthIn;
    length = lengthIn;
    weight = weightIn;
    receiver = receiverIn;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public double getLength() {
    return length;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public double calcSize(double height, double width, double length) {
    return height * width * length;
}

public void setC(Customer c) {
    this.customer = c;
}

public Customer getC() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCo(Courier c1) {
    this.courier = c1;
}

public Courier getCo() {
    return courier;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Parcel:\nHeight: " + height + "\nWidth: " + width + "\nLength: " + length + "\nWeight: " + weight;
}
```

}

//JPA method that adds a new parcel

```
    public Parcel createParcel(double heightAdd, double widthAdd, double        lengthAdd, double weightAdd, String receiverAdd,String owner,String type){
    int id = findCustomerIdByLogin(owner);
    Customer c = em.find(Customer.class, id);
    Courier co = new Courier(); 
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if(type.equals("INT")){
        System.out.println("Inside here");
        InternationalParcel int1 = new InternationalParcel(heightAdd, widthAdd, lengthAdd, weightAdd, receiverAdd);
        em.persist(int1);
        c.addParcel(int1);
        //em.persist(int1);
        co.addParcel(int1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return int1;
    } else {
        NationalParcel nat1 = new NationalParcel(heightAdd, widthAdd, lengthAdd, weightAdd,receiverAdd);
        em.persist(nat1);
        c.addParcel(nat1);
        em.persist(nat1);
        co.addParcel(nat1);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return nat1;
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcom to SO! Could you please fix the indentation of your source code and maybe strip it down to the core of your question? This is a lot of source code to read and people are more likely to help you if it's easier for them to figure out what's wrong with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your *Parcel* to a *Courier* that is not persisted in the Database yet.

You have to Persist your *Courier* Object as well.

Since you told your Courier Object that it should cascade persist its Parcel objects it should actually be enough to just persist the Courer without persisting each parcel on its own:

```
Parcel parcel;
Customer c = em.find(Customer.class, id);
Courier co = new Courier(); 
em.getTransaction().begin();
if(type.equals("INT")){
    parcel = new InternationalParcel(heightAdd, widthAdd, lengthAdd, weightAdd, receiverAdd);
} else {
    parcel = new NationalParcel(heightAdd, widthAdd, lengthAdd, weightAdd,receiverAdd);
}
co.addParcel(parcel);
em.persist(co); // <- This is what you are currently not doing! 
em.persist(parcel); // <- this might not be necessary because of cascade persist
c.addParcel(parcel);
em.getTransaction().commit();
return parcel;
```